# Причина таких знаков препинания в предложении " Он оставался таким же, как и прежде, – спокойным, трудолюбивым, скромным"

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос вот в чем: чем обоснована причина постановки тире в предложении "Он оставался таким же, как и прежде, – спокойным, трудолюбивым, скромным"?
Я считаю, что тире ставится по причине того, что "спокойным, трудолюбивым, скромным" является пояснением к "таким же", ведь после "таким же, как и прежде" может быть вставлено "то есть", "а именно". Мой друг же говорит, что это присоединительные члены предложения и что они иногда выделяются тире, когда находятся в предложении без присоединительных союзов и сопровождаются паузой. Кто прав?

Comment: вы более правы чем ваш друг )

Comment: См. §168 http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/158-tire

Comment: @shabunc, спасибо за разрешение ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Rosenthal, *Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация*

> Параллельное употребление двоеточия и тире встречается при обособлении пояснительных и уточняющих членов предложения: *Это означало одно (: —) нужно расстаться; Как долго продолжалось это молчание (: —) минуту, три, десять?; Потом началось главное (: —) поиски, нащупывание новых путей исследования; Кончался их разговор всегда одним и тем же (: —) ссорой; Сколько мне тогда было (: —) девятнадцать или двадцать?; Не знаю, когда уехать (: —) в среду или в четверг.*
>
> …
>
> В заключение можно указать, что в "конкурентной борьбе" двоеточия с тире "победителем" нередко выходит тире. Это явление отмечается многими исследователями, которые считают, что "в целом тире — знак более свободный, заходящий и во владения двоеточия" и что "выявляется тенденция к вытеснению в ряде случаев двоеточия знаком тире". Объяснить это можно особым статусом тире среди других знаков препинания: "В настоящее время тире очень употребительный и многофункциональный знак препинания. Он выполняет как грамматические (чисто синтаксические), так и эмоционально-экспрессивные функции; особенно широко используется он в последнем качестве в художественной литературе".

Russian punctuation is not codified to the extent where you can put your finger on a book, chapter and verse in a style guide and quote it as a single, unequivocal reason for every possible case.

Whoever put the em dash in this sentence put it there because felt the need to put it there. More so than putting a colon, and even more so than putting a comma, and even more so than putting other punctuation mark or nothing at all.

This is because they were reading lots of books which did the same.

The neural network in their brain responsible for Russian punctuation got wired in such a way that they had used the em dash and not some other thing in this sentence.

Other people could have put a colon in this sentence and I'm not aware of any reputable style guide which would advise otherwise.

The thing with grammar, punctuation and other style guides for natural languages is that the language and its use come first.

The guides just try to capture the implicit rules that happen to evolve in speakers' and authors' minds and codify them.

Sometimes there's no universal agreement on a rule, or the style guide author fails to capture a rule in a concise manner (this does happen, and quite often to boot).

In this case you just don't have a definite answer as to why the punctuation is one way and not the other, except "I've been reading lots of books and I just feel I need this mark here".

This is one of those cases.

You and your friend are both right and both wrong, at the same time.

You are both right because both the rules you are mentioning do exist and are not given any priorities in the style guides.

You are both wrong because the style guides' rules are not the reason you use the punctuation one or another way. The use patterns, existing in writing, are.

The "correct" punctuation is the one which does not trigger the sense of wrong in most people who have been reading lots of books.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't put a comma before the dash: "Он оставался таким же, как и прежде – спокойным, трудолюбивым, скромным" this way the sentence would look more natural. I can't prove it by any rule, though ) just an optimization, maybe?

And yes, I also see the last part as an explanation, this is why the dash looks used correctly.

Comment: Я даже не знаю, как вам писать: на английском или на русском? Вот правило о постановке запятой/тире  -  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176

Comment: Ок, спасибо за урок - буду знать!

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой, достаточно последовательный, подход: если при пояснении или уточнении используется перечисление (вариантов), особенно однотипное, использовать двоеточие, иначе - тире.

После тире следует "расшифровка", следствие из левой части до тире.

После двоеточия - "расшифровка" в форме перечисления, набора вариантов.

*Это означало одно — нужно расстаться; Как долго продолжалось это молчание: минуту, три, десять?*